# Higher-order difference quotients

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

The [Mean Value Theorem for Divided Differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem_(divided_differences)) says that if $f$ is $n$ times differentiable, and $x_0< x_1 < \dotsb < x_n$, then there is a point $\xi\in (x_0, x_n)$ such that $f[x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_n]=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}$. Therefore, if $f \in C^n$, we can conclude that $f[x_0, \dotsc, x_n] \to \frac{f^{(n)}(x^*)}{n!}$ as $(x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \to (x^*, x^*, \dotsc, x^*)$.

Suppose we  only assume that $f$ is $n$ times differentiable. How might we prove that $f[x_0, \dotsc, x_n]$ still converges to $\frac{f^{(n)}(x^*)}{n!}$ as $(x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \to (x^*, x^*, \dotsc, x^*)$ (assuming this is true)?

**Edit:** @Kelenner has pointed out that there are counterexamples for the first derivative. @Thursday has asked a question that I myself was wondering about: suppose we fix a single point. Does the result then hold?

Comment: If I have well understood the question, and  if I am not wrong, the usual example $\displaystyle f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, $f(0)=0$ with $x_0=1/2k\pi$, $x_1=1/(2k\pi+\pi/2)$ and $n=1$ gives a counter-example.

Comment: @Kelenner You're right! I overlooked that.

Comment: But maybe this can be saved by fixing one point, $x_0=x^*$? Works for 1st derivative, obviously.

Comment: @Thursday I was wondering that as well...